Optaplanner upgrade to 9.44.0 changes trigger behavior of SolverManager.solveAndListen Consumer?
I am working on an employee rostering application. I have recently upgraded to Optaplanner 9.44.0.Final (from 8.23.0) and similarly to Quarkus 3 (from 2). I am using First Fit construction heuristics and Tabu search. I am noticing a change in how the solver returns a solution before and after the upgrade which I would not expect..
Assume a very simple optimization problem where First Fit finds the best solution (best score). Therefore the local search never finds a "new best score". In this case I notice that the bestSolutionConsumer I have provided in the solverManager.solveAndListen() method is never triggered. Hence I never get information about the solution found. (Nothing is saved in my DB). Note that I observe this in Optaplanner 9.44.0.Final but not in my older version of 8.23.0. Before the upgrade, the consumer is triggered once after the end of the construction heuristics phase (or at the first step of the local search phase).
If the local search finds a "new best score" then the consumer is triggered as expected.
I know there is the option of using the overload solveAndListen method with finalBestSolutionConsumer but this does not let me see the solution (in my UI) whilst the solver is still running.

There is roughly a year of development between .23 and .44, meaning it could be a fix to some bug that  was discovered in the meantime. (In fact, I do remember we were making some changes in that area, because it isn't always correct to trigger the event at the end of CH.) More importantly though, 9.44 is now over a year old - you may want to check out Timefold Solver, a properly maintained fork of OptaPlanner.
